# Kibana am getting this, parsing_exception : [multi_match] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after [query] error

Tags: elasticsearch, search, kibana, elasticsearch-5

Am trying to fetch records from elasticsearch via kibana using multi_match query but am getting error response.

Please find my multi match query below.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
     "query": {
        "prefix" : { "code" : "M" }
    }
      "fields": [ "code", "_id" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

Am getting the below error response.

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[multi_match] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after [query]",
        "line": 4,
        "col": 15
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[multi_match] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after [query]",
    "line": 4,
    "col": 15
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot combine a `prefix` query with `multi_match`, depending on your mapping, you might be able to do it like this instead:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "*",
            "query" : "M*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Am getting this error, ` "reason": "Can only use prefix queries on keyword and text fields - not on [_id] which is of type [_id]",`

Comment: Yes, indeed, remove the `_id` on which you can only do `term` and `match` queries

Comment: Am not sure., how to do that.. do you have any reference.?

Comment: Simply remove `"_id"` from the `fields` list

Comment: Its working, but not sure., whether it will work with multiple fields. i want to search the `text` with multiple fields.

Comment: You can use any other fields, just not the `_id` one

Comment: yes., but i want to search that query in all fields. like my query is `ab` so, am expecting like it should search in all fields and bring the results like, all the field values which starts with `ab`.

Comment: What version of ES are you using?

Comment: Am using 6.2.3 version